# Rewarding the best answers of the first quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, answers, scheduled-events, answer-contests

Congratulations to **Weimer, Artemij**, and **Penelope**! Your answers will be rewarded around the end of April.

---

The [best answers of 2016](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/rewarding-the-best-answers-of-2016) have received their rewards. Now we'd like to **reward answers of the past quarter**. This time, the best two answers will receive 100 reputation points each.

- In a new answer to this question, nominate what you think was one of the best answers posted in the first quarter of 2017. Include a link to it and a few words explaining why you think it's great.
- The community will vote up and down on the various nominations.
- After three weeks (April 22, about 20:00 UTC), the two nominations with the highest scores *on this meta post* will be declared the winners.
- The two winning answers will be rewarded with bounties of 100 reputation points each, from the personal reputation stashes of the moderators. (If the scores are tied, we will reward at least two answers and give out at least 200 reputation in some way.)

To reiterate, nominated answers *must* have been originally posted in January, February, or March 2017.  You can use [this search](https://latin.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+score%3A1+created%3A2017-01..2017-03) to find candidates, but remember – the number of votes that an answer has already received isn't a perfect metric of quality!  There are many superb answers with a lower score that were posted during a lull, or that didn't make it onto the Hot Network Questions list, which therefore didn't get as much attention (and votes) as others.  So this might be an opportunity for some of those excellent overlooked answers to get the attention they deserve.

For this contest to succeed we need your nominations and votes!  We intend to continue holding contests in following quarters, and the level of community participation will directly impact for how long we can or will continue.

Remember, the deadline for both nominations and votes is **April 22 at 20:00 UTC**.  Post your nominations early to ensure that they get the most visibility possible!

Comment: I should add that anyone with at least 75 reputation points is free to [reward any answer they like](http://latin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) whenever they want.

Comment: **Note about the lock:** This question has been locked due to the voting period having ended. The lock message is however inaccurate in that it is not considered a bad or inappropriate question. It is merely locked for historical preservation of the poll.

Answer (score 5):

I liked [C. M. Weimer's answer to *What is “Winter is Coming” in Latin?*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/2973/79).
The answer came some eight months after the question, but it was worth the wait: it very carefully explains the differences in nuance between translation options and offers classical examples.

Answer (score 4):

Artemij Keidan has only posted one answer so far, but it was great.
His answer to my question about [what we have learned about Latin in the last century](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2965/79) contains insight that only an expert can give.
Such high level research summaries are very rare on our site.

Answer (score 4):

I found [Penelope's explanation of why did Roman authors never feel a need for word spacing](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/2685/12) quite interesting – the advice from Cicero and Quintilian, as well as helpful analysis including links to related resources.  Overall, nicely presented and full of valuable info.