# Rewarding the best answers of the second quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, answers, scheduled-events, answer-contests

The voting has ended and this question has therefore been locked.
**Congratulations Ben and Penelope!**

---

What were the best answers of the second quarter (April, May, June) of 2017?
**Nominate your favorites and vote on other people's suggestions!**
To nominate an answer, simply post it an answer to this question with a link and brief description of the answer.

The nominated answers must have been originally posted in one of these months.
To get you started, [here is a search for all answers from this period with positive score](https://latin.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20score%3a1%20created%3a2017-04..2017-06).
The answer doesn't have to be accepted, and it doesn't matter if it has already received a bounty.

**Everyone is invited to nominate and vote!**
After three weeks (**July 24**, but I make no promise about the exact time), the two nominations with the highest scores on this meta post will be declared the winners.
The two winning answers will be rewarded with bounties of 100 reputation points each, from the personal reputation stashes of the moderators.
(If the scores are tied, we will reward at least two answers and give out at least 200 reputation in some way.)

Of course, anyone with 75 or more reputation is [free to reward any answer they like at any time](http://latin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).
Consider this contest also as an opportunity to highlight some hidden gems that received few votes but are excellent in quality.

Previous similar events:
[Best of 2016](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/251/79), [Best of first quarter of 2017](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/269/79).

Comment: **Note about the lock:** This question has been locked due to the voting period having ended. The lock message is however inaccurate in that it is not considered a bad or inappropriate question. It is merely locked for historical preservation of the poll.

Answer (score 5):

I nominate this answer by Penelope: [What did a *cellarius* do?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4069/what-did-a-cellarius-do/4123#4123)

It lively tells the duties of a *cellarius* in Ancient Roman times.

Answer (score 5):

This one about [Google Translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/what-is-google-translate-good-for-latin/4352#4352) by Ben Kovitz cannot be overseen. Especially noteworthy in his favor is the 25-times-upvoted comment:

> I joined just to upvote this. I think such an explanation would have its place on non-specific sites too, like linguistics.se or even cs.se