# Rewarding the best answers of 2018

Tags: discussion, answers, scheduled-events, answer-contests

The voting period has ended.
Thanks for everyone taking part, and congratulations to TKR, Charlie, and sumelic!
(The bounties will be distributed shortly.)

---

What were the best answers of the year 2018?
**Nominate your favorites and vote on other people's suggestions!**
To nominate an answer, simply post it an answer to this question with a link and brief description of the answer.
You can nominate as many answers as you want.

The nominated answers must have been originally posted in 2018.
To get you started, [here is a search for all answers from this period with positive score](https://latin.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+score%3A1+created%3A2018).
The answer doesn't have to be accepted, and it doesn't matter if it has already received a bounty.

**Everyone is invited to nominate and vote!**
After about a month (**February 4**, but I make no promise about the exact time), the three nominations with the highest scores on this meta post will be declared the winners.
The **three winning answers** will be rewarded with bounties of **100 reputation points** each, from the personal reputation stashes of the moderators.
(If the scores are tied, we will reward at least three answers and give out at least 300 reputation in some way.)

Of course, anyone with 75 or more reputation is [free to reward any answer they like at any time](http://latin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).
Consider this contest also as an opportunity to highlight some hidden gems that received few votes but are excellent in quality.

Previous similar events:
[Best of 2016](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/251/79), [Best of first quarter of 2017](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/269/79), [Best of second quarter of 2017](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/303/79), [Best of second half of 2017](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/322/79).
We will probably continue these events annually unless there are wishes for higher frequency.
Suggestions concerning such rewards and events are welcome in comments, [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm), or [a new meta question](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 5):

I'll nominate TKR's answer to [What cases were used in compounds?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/7037/9), which gives some interesting examples of compounds with first elements that are not bare stems.

Answer (score 4):

I want to nominate Charlie's answer to his own question, [What did "actuālis" actually mean in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7120/what-did-actu%c4%81lis-actually-mean-in-latin/7122#7122), on the meaning change of the Spanish word *actual*, derived from Latin **actualis**.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to nominate sumelic's answer considering the use of macrons in [this response](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6211/is-it-acceptable-regular-to-use-diacritics-macron-in-written-texts/6212#6212).

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to sound like I'm blowing my own horn, so if you think it sounds like that, *please* downvote. I also count on Joonas not to count the nomination itself as a vote, if judged appropriate.

I'm particularly fond of my answer to [What are the moon phases in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6079/what-are-the-moon-phases-in-latin/6082#6082) That is exactly why I think I might not be the best to assess it, more so as a non-native English speaker writing in English. I just wanted to make sure it is not due to oblivion that it doesn't get into the contest.